# What is wrong with this PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have this pl/sql code block,

```
set serveroutput 
clear screen;

DECLARE
  TYPE    recPriceList is Record(comno varchar2(3),t$cpls varchar2(6),t$dsca varchar(100), Customers int,minExpiry varchar2(20),groupCount int,undefGroups int);
  comno   VARCHAR2(6)   :='010';
  sSql    VARCHAR2(1000):=' ';
  c      sys_refcursor;
  r       recPricelist;
BEGIN

  sql:=q'[select distinct  lpad('010',3,'0'), t$cpls cpls,t$dsca,count(t$cuno),null  Customers,null,null  
        from baan.ttccom010010 c  
        join baan.ttcmcs034010 p on c.t$cpls = p.t$cplt  
        where trim(t$cpls) is not null    
        group by T$CPLS,T$DSCA  order by t$cpls']';

  OPEN c FOR sSql ;
  LOOP
    FETCH c INTO r;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.comno||' | '||r.t$cpls|| ' dsca='|| r.t$dsca);
    EXIT   WHEN c%notfound;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I cant figure why the following error being thrown when I run this block

```
SQLPLUS command failed - not enough arguments Error starting at line : 5 in command - DECLARE   TYPE    recPriceList is Record(comno
varchar2(3),t$cpls varchar2(6),t$dsca varchar(100), Customers
int,minExpiry varchar2(20),groupCount int,undefGroups int);   comno  
VARCHAR2(6)   :='010';   sSql    VARCHAR2(1000):=' ';   c     
sys_refcursor;   r       recPricelist; BEGIN

  sql:=q'[select distinct  lpad('010',3,'0'), t$cpls
cpls,t$dsca,count(t$cuno),null  Customers,null,null  
        from baan.ttccom010010 c  
        join baan.ttcmcs034010 p on c.t$cpls = p.t$cplt  
        where trim(t$cpls) is not null    
        group by T$CPLS,T$DSCA  order by t$cpls']';
       OPEN c FOR sSql ;   LOOP
    FETCH c INTO r;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.comno||' | '||r.t$cpls|| ' dsca='|| r.t$dsca);
    EXIT   WHEN c%notfound;   END LOOP; END; Error report - ORA-06550: line 9, column 6: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting
one of the following:

   %
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Sorry guys, the problem was an un-neccssary quote charater at the end of the quoted sSql string.

Comment: TonyP, yes and you also miss a `CLOSE` cursor statement.!

Answer (score 3):

**SQL*Plus command**

```
set serveroutput ON; 
clear screen;
```

**PL/SQL Block**

You need to have the Variable as `sSql`, also I corrected the `extra single quote` in the assignment!

Added block to `CLOSE` the *cursor* as well!

```
DECLARE
  TYPE    recPriceList is Record(comno varchar2(3),t$cpls varchar2(6),t$dsca varchar(100), Customers int,minExpiry varchar2(20),groupCount int,undefGroups int);
  comno   VARCHAR2(6)   :='010';
  sSql    VARCHAR2(1000):=' ';
  c      sys_refcursor;
  r       recPricelist;
BEGIN

  sSql := q'[select distinct  lpad('010',3,'0'), t$cpls cpls,t$dsca,count(t$cuno),null  Customers,null,null  
        from baan.ttccom010010 c  
        join baan.ttcmcs034010 p on c.t$cpls = p.t$cplt  
        where trim(t$cpls) is not null    
        group by T$CPLS,T$DSCA  order by t$cpls]';

  OPEN c FOR sSql ;
  LOOP
    FETCH c INTO r;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(r.comno||' | '||r.t$cpls|| ' dsca='|| r.t$dsca);
    EXIT   WHEN c%notfound;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE c;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

you assign a value for non-existing variable `sql`:

```
  sql:=q'[select distinct  lpad('010',3,'0'), t$cpls cpls,t$dsca,count(t$cuno),null  Customers,null,null  
        from baan.ttccom010010 c  
        join baan.ttcmcs034010 p on c.t$cpls = p.t$cplt  
        where trim(t$cpls) is not null    
        group by T$CPLS,T$DSCA  order by t$cpls']';
```

simply change the variable name to `sSql`